# How to get coordinates on tapping map in Phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, geolocation, leaflet

Currently i am showing map in my phonegap application using leaflet.js. i want to get coordinates of user tapped location in a map in phonegap application. what is the best approach to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please familiarize yourself with the [Leaflet reference: it will make this kind of question very easy to answer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html).

- Listen to a [click](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-click) event on the map with `map.on('click'`
- Get the [latlng property of the event object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#mouse-event)